# Multiple WCF Services within IIS 8

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, http, iis

I Have following architecture with 3 components: 1x ASP MVC4 application communicating with WCF Service1 over HTTP which redirect requests into WCF Service2. (Please note that this is simplified case, but this is problematic scenario)

```
+--------+           +--------+              +--------+
|ASP MVC4|----WCF--->|Service1| ----WCF----> |Service2|
+--------+           +--------+              +--------+
```

When i deploy all into one IIS 8 all into Same application pool it works only when i send ONE request from ASP MVC4. When i send multiple concurrent requests into Service1 it stops working. Multiple concurrent request never reach Service2 (according to log4net) and pretty much whole IIS freeze and Visual Studio freeze as well.

When i deploy at least ONE component to IIS Express or into different application pool it starts working again (even for multiple requests).

I dont know where to start debugging this feature and also i dont know what can cause this bug. I think it will be related with internal Threads of Application pool in IIS but this is a long shot.

Question is HOW to determine what cause this and how to solve it.

Well so i tried WCF trace details:
After problem reconstruction turned on logging on Service1 and on Service2

**Service1 log:**

```
 4x last event  Description Sent a message over a channel.
```

**Service2 log:** 
Not even created file - looks like this service stopped receiving any requests.

Comment: "It stops working"? What does that mean?

Comment: Well it means that requests wont reach Service2 and IIS freeze and stop responding to everything else. (even Service2 become unreachable)

Comment: I have a similar setup in Production where a proxy WCF service redirects requests to another WCF service, and they both run in the same app pool. I have never seen any lockups like you describe. You say "Visual Studio freeze as well" so you are presumably running this through the debugger, if you run it standalone does the problem still happen?

Comment: Yep it does. we can reproduce this behavior on two different computers (both running Windows 8.1 with IIS 8). Visual studio freeze because it cant deattach its debugger from IIS - because IIS become frozen.

Comment: Have you tried WCF logging?

Comment: Acutally i didnt. I ll try- thanks for suggestion i almost forgot about WCF logging.

Comment: Well so i added details from WCF logging. Service1 Sent message over channel. Service2 didnt receive nothing or didnt create wcf trace log at all.

Comment: We had a similar issue where we were seeing hangs when we had two inter-dependent services in a single appdomain.  They always seemed to occur when a call was made from one service to another from either `App_Code\Initialize.cs` or `Global.asax`'s `Application_Startup`.  Never did track it down, but we were not hung in user code.

Comment: As far as i can tell i am not stuck in user source code too.